# Проблема с получением сслыки

Tags: javascript

Как записать ссылку в переменную?

```
<div id="market_actions">
    <div>
        <div style="height: 24px;">
            <a href="http://test.com">Найти</a>
        </div>
    <div>Продано</div>
    <a><span>Продать</span></a>
    /* еще много div и a */
</div>
```

Пытаюсь так, но не находит мою `a`. Что я делаю не правильно?

```
            var re = document.getElementById("market_actions");
            console.log(re);
            var re1 = re.querySelectorAll("a");
            console.log(re1);
            var re2 = re1[0].href;
            console.log(re2);
```

Comment: market_actions и imarket_actions это разные идентификаторы, вот и не находит

Answer (score 2):

Если вы правильно скопировали свой код в вопрос, то всё дело в опечатке.

Ваш элемент:

```
<div id="imarket_actions">
```

Ваш селектор:

```
var re = document.getElementById("market_actions");
```

В одном случае `imarket_actions`, в другом — `market_actions`.

Comment: Не стоит писать ответы об опечатках, вместо этого стоит закрыть вопрос

Comment: @andreymal после ответа оставил голос за закрытие, не всегда помню, какие там есть формулировки :) Если есть серьёзная необходимость, ответ могу удалить.

Comment: Это опечатка моя. Мне он выдает ошибку `Cannot read property 'href' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test() {
  var re = document.getElementById("market_actions");
  console.log(re);
  var re1 = re.querySelectorAll("a");
  console.log(re1);
  var re2 = re1[0].href;
  console.log(re2);
}
```

```html
<div id="market_actions">
  <div>
    <div style="height: 24px;">
      <a href="http://test.com">Найти</a>
    </div>
    <div>Продано</div>
    <a><span>Продать</span></a> /* еще много div и a */
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="test()">Click</button>
```